# Custom Analytics settings when installing Optimize through gtag

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, gtag.js, google-optimize

Do I need to add custom Analytics settings in the gtag when installing Optimize if I have GA implemented through GTM?

With the analytics.js snippet, you had to make sure to include the same custom Analytics setting as for the Google Analytics tag in GTM (under Fields to set). [This is described here](https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7359264)

I can't find any similar documentation on whether this is also the case for implementation through the gtag.

In this case, Google Analytics is implemented through GTM, but I want to add Google Optimize to the site by using the gtag snippet, to make sure it is loaded before GTM. I guess I have to add `{ 'send_page_view': false }` since that will be done by the GTM tag, but how about custom Analytics settings?

Comment: Why do you want Optimize to be loaded before GTM? Isn't it enough to have it loaded before Analytics within GTM? Nevertheless, the requirement of having the same Optimize-Analyitcs setting is not specific for the implementation, but a general requirement.

Comment: Thanks! I want Optimize to begin loading as fast as possible, without having to wait for GTM.